# HTML button not changing value nor redirecting

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following button in a website running on flask and script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#realScanButton").click(function() {
    clickEnBoton();
  });
});

function clickEnBoton() {
  alert("1");
  $("#realScanButton").prop('value', 'Scanning...');
  alert("2");
  $("#realScanButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  alert("3");
  $("#realScanButton").attr('href', 'http://localhost:5000/scan')
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <button href="scan" id="realScanButton" type="button">Scan Network</button>
</div>
```

And the only thing this is doing is disabling the button but it does not change the text or redirects to the website I want to.

Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Just to be clear, the button gets disabled (i.e. `$("#realScanButton").attr('disabled','disabled');` is called), but the other 2 lines don't seem to change anything? Can you open the chrome/firefox inspector and check the actual html source code when you click it, see what it's modifying?

Comment: @PaoloAgVa Try changing `href = "scan"` to `href = "javascript:void(0)"` and add this code: `onclick = "clickEnBoton()"`   This should fix your issue. You were not calling the function by the looks of it.

Comment: A `<button>` is not an `<a>` and has no `href` . Setting `value` won't change it's text either. What are you trying to accomplish with the `href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set html for the button to update the text, 
i.e. '$("#realScanButton").html('Scanning...');'
and to redirect to a different page use,
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5000/scan';

Answer (score 0):

Change your `clickEnBoton` function as below

```
function clickEnBoton(){
    alert("1");
    $("#realScanButton").text('Scanning...');
    alert("2");
    $("#realScanButton").attr('disabled','disabled');
    alert("3");
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5000/scan';
    return true;
}
```

or you can do simply by

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#realScanButton").click(function() {
        alert("1");
        $(this).text('Scanning...');
        alert("2");
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        alert("3");
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5000/scan';
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changin your function like so:

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#realScanButton").click(function() {
            clickEnBoton(); 
        });
    });

    function clickEnBoton(){
        alert("1");
        $("#realScanButton").html('Scanning...');
        alert("2");
        $("#realScanButton").attr('disabled','disabled');
        alert("3");
        
        //this will not run, until btn will be enabled again and clicked
        $("#realScanButton").click(function() { 
          window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5000/scan'
        });
        return true;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <button href="scan" id="realScanButton" type="button">Scan Network</button>
</div>
```

But take care that changing the button action, will not run until you click again, if you want to inmediatly redirect the page after click, change the function like this:

```
function clickEnBoton(){
        alert("1");
        $("#realScanButton").html('Scanning...');
        alert("2");
        $("#realScanButton").attr('disabled','disabled');
        alert("3");


         window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5000/scan'

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: How can it be clicked again if it is disabled on the first click? Doesn't make sense

Comment: make sense if he wants to enable it again in another part of the code after some processing